# input filepath and pass to string literal

Tags: python

I am working on a script that takes user input in the form of a filepath for a SAS data set. To get the filepath to work when developing the program I use

```
data= r'//filepath/file.sas7bdat'
```

But I want now to pass the filepath from user input like this:

```
path = input("Filepath: ")
```

To be used in

```
df = pd.read_sas(data, format = 'sas7bdat', encoding="cp1252")
```

But I cant figure out how to pass the filepath to the use the literal r' ', something like this

```
data=r'path'
```

Comment: If I may, I'd recommend you pass the file name as a parameter if possible to your actual script. That way you get tab-completion and other neat things. `python myscript.py /filepath/file.sas7bdat` and do `path = sys.argv[1]` instead. For the record tho, passing `r' '` only means it's a raw string, so backslashes etc won't need to be escaped when **writing** the string. It will still be a escaped character behind the scenes. So there's no difference in `r' '` and a normal string in the net result. So don't worry to much about it unless you know why this would be an issue.

Comment: thanks! Will try that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw string is only useful when you hard-code a string literal with backslashes in it. Since you now want `path` to be from the user's input, there is no need to use a raw string at all, and you can use `path` as it is returned by `input()` directly:

```
df = pd.read_sas(path, format = 'sas7bdat', encoding="cp1252")
```

Comment: I get the following error in that case: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"\\\\filepath\file.sas7bdat"'

Comment: But seems to work when I pass the filepath without qoutes! Thanks!